# I was trying to test the FocusState and got the error that it is only available in iOS 15 or later. the iPhone 12 Pro simulator shows iOS 15.0

Tags: swiftui, focus

I downloaded the beta version of Xcode 13 and tried a build which failed with the following error. 'FocusState' is only available in iOS 15.0 or newer'

trying to figure out if I missed something and did not download everything.

Comment: Your project has to be for iOS 15 or newer and or mark that view with @available

Comment: I had the same problem. This question and the below answer helped. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's due to the fact that the app template sets Target Deployment to `iOS 14`. To solve it, select the app target and select `iOS 15.0` in the Deployment Info section.
[image: Visual description of the answer]